# How to define a F# abstract member with empty type-signature

Tags: .net, class, f#, unit-type

According to this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483468.aspx), all abstract members of a class must have a `type-signature`. But I want to define a abstract class that has void input parameter and void return type. And `void` is not valid keyword in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes on this.  Anyone who downvoted care to comment on why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, you typically use the `unit` type where you would use the `void` keyword in C#.  So an example of what you're looking for would be:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type MyAbstractClass() =
    abstract MyMethod : unit -> unit

type MyDerivedClass() =
    inherit MyAbstractClass()
    override this.MyMethod() = printf "Do something here..."
```

Comment: It is worth adding that the F# compiler actually compiles `unit` to `void` in most of the cases (including this one).